# Javascript touch events glitchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, touch, mobile-safari

I'm currently creating some sliders in Javascript, for use with touch, and the results I'm getting aren't all that I'd hoped for.

When holding down one of the slider handles, it gets a translucent dark grey overlay (like all links do when you hold them down on iOS). Once it's done this, the handle can't be dragged.

This makes them exceptionally difficult to use, as you can imagine.

Another problem I'm having is with the page scrolling. Unless I get a near-perfect horizontal swipe, iOS safari thinks I'm trying to scroll the page and stops the js.

I know its possible to fix these problems, because jQuery mobile doesn't have them with their slider. I've been through the source code for the jQuery mobile slider, but I can't find how they're preventing these problems.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

jQuery mobile's slider - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/slider/

Comment: Why don't you use their slider? They have a large team working hard on mobile events and it works excellently.

Comment: @Jivings It's not customisable enough, and doesn't suit my needs. I'm specifically creating a colour slider, I tried using jQuery mobile but found it too invasive on everything else.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to go through the arduous process of determining touch and drag events from click events. I expect that is the problem.

Comment: @Jivings Could you expand on what you mean by 'determining touch and drag events from click events'?

Comment: I can't say I understand how the framework does it, but they 'abstract away' mouse and touch events so it can be determined when a user is using a mouse on a PC and when they are using a finger on a touchscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1 - Grey Box on click:

Add this css for all elements:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

You might also want to use these as well to stop highlighting:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Problem 2 - Stop Scrolling

You'll need a handler for the events touchstart and touchend and you'll need to add this to the handlers.

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Do note this will stop scrolling and zooming as well. If you still want zooming you will likely need to re-implement or use an additional library.

Good reference info on touch events

Tutorial:
http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/

Apple Docs (this has a good explanation on the relation between touch and mouse events):
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already had event.preventDefault(); but in the wrong handler! All works lovely now.

Comment: liked the tip on tap-highlight-color. much appreciated!